# How to access elements of atom in clojure

Tags: clojure

```clj
(def input (atom[
#{
  [
    {:site-id 1} 
    {:both-unconf [[27 4] "Humidity"]} 
    {:own-unconf|other-conf [[30 1] "Humidity"]} 
    {:other-site-unconf 2500} 
    {:other-site-conf 2500} 
      [
        {:site-id 0} 
        {:both-unconf [[20 1] "Temperature"]} 
        {:own-unconf|other-conf [[22 0] "Temperature"]} 
        {:other-site-unconf 3} 
        {:other-site-conf 1}
      ]
  ]
} :something-else
]))
```

I want to access site-id from this atom map.

I am using the following code but not getting the output.

```
(->> @input
     (map #(:site-id %))
     (into [])
```

Comment: Are you sure that your input is correct? Those nested lists?

Comment: With the nesting right now, to get all :site-id you need to use tree-seq or something similar to walk the hierarchy.  I'd double check, if this is really your intentional data structure and not just some happy little conj accident.

Comment: Actually,the input has been generated by me,by merging two maps.

Comment: I have changed the input to-- #atom[#{[[{:site-id (2)} {:both-unconf [[817.9834427857821 229.6681612525713] "CO2"]} {:own-unconf|other-conf [[697.2878144908756 123.50870427784022] "CO2"]} {:other-site-unconf 161/1250} {:other-site-conf 1089/1250}] [{:site-id (0)} {:both-unconf [[21.69303694863922 0.6983724350490743] "Temperature"]} {:own-unconf|other-conf [[21.306901268115865 0.6576811158640271] "Temperature"]} {:other-site-unconf 1323/10000} {:other-site-conf 8677/10000}]]} 0x75bb41ee]

Comment: That's better, but still strange.  I don't know how you end up with those vectors of single-key maps.  I think that therein lies your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
(def input
  (atom [#{[{:site-id 1}
            {:both-unconf [[27 4] "Humidity"]} 
            {:own-unconf|other-conf [[30 1] "Humidity"]} 
            {:other-site-unconf 2500} 
            {:other-site-conf 2500} 
            [{:site-id 0} 
             {:both-unconf [[20 1] "Temperature"]} 
             {:own-unconf|other-conf [[22 0] "Temperature"]} 
             {:other-site-unconf 3} 
             {:other-site-conf 1}]]}
         :something-else]))
```

This data structure is very strange.  It is

- an atom, containing
- a vector, containing
- a set, containing
- a vector, containing
- a bunch of single-key maps, and then
- another vector, containing
- a bunch of single-key maps
- etc., presumably

If we allow for the `:something-else` to be something else, it should be, to be useful:

- an atom, containing
- a vector, containing
- a set, containing
- a bunch of maps

So:

```
(def input
  (atom [#{{:site-id 1
            :both-unconf [[27 4] "Humidity"]
            :own-unconf|other-conf [[30 1] "Humidity"]
            :other-site-unconf 2500
            :other-site-conf 2500} 
           {:site-id 0
            :both-unconf [[20 1] "Temperature"]
            :own-unconf|other-conf [[22 0] "Temperature"]
            :other-site-unconf 3
            :other-site-conf 1}}
         :something-else]))
```

If it was like this, then

```
(->> @input
     first
     (mapv :site-id))
```

would work.

Comment: Then how can I create a structure like this in clojure as I am new to clojure.I have calculated all of these values my input is a atom which stores detail about about 2 different elements having same characteristics like :site-id,etc.I have created two maps and joined them to input.How can I get the output of individual maps as you have shown in the code above

Comment: I don't know what your actual inputs look like.  Maybe amend the question, or make a new one?